# Interfaces and pointer receivers

Tags: go, go-interface

I am newbie gopher and trying to get my head around the pointer receivers and interfaces.

```
type Foo interface {
    foo()
}
type Bar struct {}
func (b *Bar) foo() {}
```

based on the above definitions..

```
--- Allowed ---------
b := Bar{}
b.foo()

--- Not allowed ----- 

var foo Foo = Bar{}
```

Get compiler error:
cannot use Bar literal (type Bar) as type Foo in assignment:
    Bar does not implement Foo (foo method has pointer receiver)

I understand that compiler is doing some pointer conversion and de-referencing on our behalf in the first scenario. Why doesn't it do the same thing in the second scenario ?

Comment: So you aren't asking how to make it work, you are asking __why__ it doesn't work? (btw `var foo Foo = &Bar{}` works)

Answer (score 25):

Short answer `var foo Foo = Bar{}` is not working because the concrete value stored in an interface is not addressable.

**Longer Version**

Please read https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MethodSets

> It is legal to call a pointer-valued method on anything that is
>   already a pointer or whose address can be taken. It is legal to call a
>   value method on anything which is a value or whose value can be
>   dereferenced.

With respect to the above explanation, your code

```
b := Bar{}
b.foo()
```

works because `b` is addressable.

> The concrete value stored in an interface is not addressable.
>   Therefore, when you call a method on an interface, it must either have
>   an identical receiver type or it must be directly discernible from the
>   concrete type: pointer- and value-receiver methods can be called with
>   pointers and values respectively, as you would expect. Value-receiver
>   methods can be called with pointer values because they can be
>   dereferenced first. Pointer-receiver methods cannot be called with
>   values, however, because the value stored inside an interface has no
>   address. When assigning a value to an interface, the compiler ensures
>   that all possible interface methods can actually be called on that
>   value, and thus trying to make an improper assignment will fail on
>   compilation.

According to the above explanation the concrete value stored in an interface is not addressable and hence the code,

```
var foo Foo = Bar{}
```

will not work because the concrete value stored in an interface, in this case `Bar{}`, is not addressable.

Comment: Your answer uses more a definitive source than mine. Hope yours ends up accepted. Cheers!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

The explanation lies in the fact that when dealing with the concrete struct itself, it has the proper information to handle this automatically. You can read [in the tour here](https://gobyexample.com/methods) that:

> Go automatically handles conversion between values and pointers for
>   method calls.

But when you are dealing with an `interface{}` type, it has less information on what is actually contained in the variable. It just knows there is a `foo()` method. But there is a subtlety here that requires extra explanation so here is an example.

https://play.golang.org/p/Y0fJcAISw1

```
type Foo interface {
    foo()
}
type Bar struct {}
func (b *Bar) foo() {}

type Baz struct {}
func (b Baz) foo() {}

func main() {
    b := Bar{}
    b.foo()

    var v Foo = &Bar{}
    // v = Bar{} // fails
    v.foo()

    v = Baz{}
    v.foo()
    v = &Baz{} // works too
    v.foo()
}
```

Notice that `&Baz{}` works even though it has a value receiver, but not the reverse. The reason being that a `*Baz` points to exactly **one** `Baz`, both of which exist (the pointer and the value), so the value is easily obtained. When you try to do `v = Bar{}`, the value exists, but the pointer does not, and Go will not automatically create one for an `interface{}` value.

This is all explained in detail under the **Pointers and interfaces** heading [in this blog post](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go)

Comment: Nothing of this fails. I've tested the code and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Sebi2020 Uncomment line 18 and try again. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault.

Comment: @Sebi2020 No worries. I probably should have left the example as uncommented so it was more clear where it would fail. Mixed feelings giving out a broken example though, haha. Guess that's the focus of this particular Q/A though.

Answer (score 4):

Half of your question depends on whether your value is addressable or not:

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the address operation `&x` generates a
>   pointer of type `*T` to `x`. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either:
>
> - a variable,
> - pointer indirection, or
> - slice indexing operation; or
> - a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or
> - an array indexing operation of an addressable array.
>
> As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` may also be a
>   (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.
>
> — [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

`Bar{}` is a composite literal, thus it is not addressable. You may type `&Bar{}` to create an object of type `*Bar`, but that is listed as "an exception to the addressability requirement", reinforcing the idea that `Bar{}` is not addressable in itself.

Variable `b` of type `Bar` can invoke `b.foo()` despite `Bar.foo()` requiring a pointer receiver for a good reason:

> A method call `x.m()` is valid if the method set of (the type of) `x`
>   contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter
>   list of `m`. **If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`,
>   `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`**
>
> — [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

However, that does not mean `Bar.foo()` is in the method set of `b`. This is because `b` has type `Bar` while `Bar.foo()` receives a value of type `*Bar`:

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type `T`
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method
>   set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the
>   method set of `T`).
>
> — from [Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

Because the method sets of `b` and the `Foo` interface differ, you cannot use  `var foo Foo = b`, despite `b.foo()` being converted to `(&b).foo()` by the compiler. Otherwise, `var foo Foo = Bar{}` would work. You may, however, use either of the following since `Bar.foo()` receives a `*Bar`:

```
var foo Foo = &b
var foo Foo = &Bar{}
```

Comment: I'm not being demeaning to your answer at all, or suggesting a change, but this is probably way above someone referring to themselves as a newbie gopher. I love that we now have 3 answers of varying depths of explanation.